# Мой дачный участок(,) шириной 200 метров(,) – это рай

Tags: запятые

Нужны ли запятые?

`Мой дачный участок(,) шириной 200 метров(,) – это рай на планете Земля.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы написала так: *Мой дачный участок, **шириной 200 метров**, — это рай.*

Видится мне здесь пауза, надо подчеркнуть ширину. Для чего? Смысл примерно такой: *Мой дачный участок, **шириной всего-то 200 метров,** — это рай.*

А без обособления **читается хуже** (неравновесная конструкция), да и выглядит **не художественно**. Это какой-то **технический** стиль получается.

Comment: Если не обособлен оборот, то получается, что есть несколько у человека дачучастков и что он говорит именно про тот, который шириной 200 метров.

Comment: Да, в этом случае имеется в виду конкретный участок.

Comment: @Sharon А почему всë-таки стоят запятые? Уточнение, присоединение?

Comment: Это уточнение и дополнение одновременно.  Мой участок – здесь имеется в виду конкретный участок, далее следует дополнительная информация об этом участке.  А если не обособить, то получится, что участков несколько.

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю, что запятые таки не нужны.

В русском языке нет правил для обособления существительных в творительном падеже с их зависимыми словами, так что нет оснований ставить запятые.

***Мой дачный участок шириной 200 метров — это рай.***

Или так:

***Мой дачный участок (шириной 200 метров) — это рай.***