# У меня есть один большой участок(,) длиною в 100 метров

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> У меня есть один большой участок(,) длиною в 100 метров.

Comment: Лучше поставить запятую, по ответу Sharon на этот вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475432/Мой-дачный-участок-шириной-200-метров-это-рай. Да и не только по нему.